# How does std::cout format the output?

Tags: c++, c++17

How does std::cout work?
The following code doesn't pass certain test cases for a question on HackerEarth.com:

```
double n,a,b;
while(t--){
    cin>>n>>a>>b;
    long long x = round(b*n*1.0/(a+b));
    cout<<((a*x*x) + b*(n-x)*(n-x))<<endl;
}
```

while, the following one passes all of them:

```
double n,a,b;
while(t--){
    cin>>n>>a>>b;
    long long x = round(b*n*1.0/(a+b));
    long long ans = (a*x*x) + b*(n-x)*(n-x);
    cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

Why does it happen that when I store the calculated value in a variable, then only the test cases are passed?
Does the value change if directly printed to console?
I am a newbie to C++.

Comment: In the first case the code prints a `double`, in the second case it prints a `long long` obtained by truncating the double to the nearest integer less than or equal to it. The two values are not necessarily the same, and the default formats for printing floating points vs integer types may also be different.

Comment: Could you provide an example where the output differs? (In addition to giving us something concrete to work with, you might find that the concrete case reveals that the first code can output a non-integer...)

Comment: @JaMiT The test cases are hidden, though, I got your point of getting a non-integer as output in the first case, while the same gets truncated when stored in a long long variable. Thanks.

Comment: @AkarshModi *"The test cases are hidden"* -- this is not an acceptable excuse. One of the skills expected of a programmer is the ability to devise test cases, and not rely solely on others to do so. When you were informed that some test cases failed, one of the reactions you should have had is to try more test cases until you find one that fails. (At which point, you would be able to augment your question with a concrete example.)

Comment: Thanks for the good advice! I'll surely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The output format "chosen" by `cout` (or any `std::ostream`) depends on the type which is being outputted (specifically, it depends on the implementation of [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for that type).

Let's look at what types are at play in both cases.

In your first example, you are outputting a `double`, since `a`, `b`, and `n` are doubles. Even though `x` is a `long long`, the expression is a double due [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

In the second example, you are outputting a `long long`, since that is the type of `ans`. Note that your calculation of `ans` may be truncated, since it is being computed as a double (for the reasons explained above) but stored in a `long long`.

Without knowing the details of the test cases you are talking about, one difference in the output is that doubles will likely be output in decimal notation (e.g. `1.23` or `1.0`) whereas a `long long` (or any integral type) will be output as a whole number (note: there are ways to change this behavior, which I'm omitting here for simplicity).